# How to show all product reviews in one page in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, product, review, singlepage

I want to show all the product reviews in a single review page only. How to do this?

Comment: You need to provide more details and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new front controller in a module; pass the id product as parameter and get all comments linked to this product.